# What is main_table in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

Many times i am debugging SQL Query in Magento. But i am little confuse about usages of `main_table` in SQL query in Magento.

I can't find any table named with  "`main_table`" in database.

Can anyone tell me the concept about main_table in Magento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**main_table** is an alias of your table name i.e. you have table name **abc** in the following SQL query.

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `abc` AS `main_table` ORDER BY `main_table`.`bid_end` desc
```

Magento collection will default generate alias of your table i.e. abc as main table.

Comment: Means i create collection as:

`$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());`

and i get query as below:

SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`

that means `sales_flat_order_grid` is my main table...Right ??

Comment: you can check echo Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->getSelect();